# ¿Cómo puedo instanciar un objecto utilizando una variable string con el nombre de la clase?

Tags: c#, reflexión

Algo como esto es lo que tengo

```
        frm = new nombredelaclase();
        frm.Show();
```

Comment: Bienvenido a  SOes, te voy a hacer un par de preguntas para aclarar un poco esto, de que tipo es frm ?  suongo que es un `Form`. Aparte de esto te invito a que des el [recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y también puedes leer este apartado que te ayudará a [formular buenas preguntas](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y también podrías leer como hacer un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). No dudes en preguntar, entre todos podemos formar una buena comunidad con buen contenido. Abrazo.

Answer (score 3):

Si puedes. Este ejemplo es suponiendo que tu clase esta en el mismo assembly donde esta este codigo.

```
var tipo = "PruebaFormulario";
var form = (Form)Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), tipo);
form.Show();
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!! pero decidí resolver mi problema de otra forma

Answer (score -1):

Otra opción es que puedes agregar la referencia a la clase que necesitas en el apartado de `using MiClase;`

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!! pero decidí resolver mi problema de otra forma